# Send file via NFC from Galaxy S2 Plus and Sony vaio with Ubuntu OS

Tags: linux, file-transfer, nfc

I have a problem with sharing files between my *Galaxy S2* phone and a *Sony Vaio* model SVF1521DCXW with NFC support<sup>1</sup>. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop version and I don't have any idea how can I use NFC to send a single photo to my PC. When I enable NFC on my phone and put it on the NFC sign on my laptop nothing happens.

I also enabled NFC on my Ubuntu machine, and I see my NFC is ON in Ubuntu. As it is usually done between Android devices, I've held my S2 back-to-back on the Vaio while running Ubuntu and Win8. I hear a sound on my Win8 and it opens a url on chrome browser – but I get nothing to transfer.

---

<sup>**1:** To be clear: *both* devices have NFC support, see the specs [at GSMArena for the S2](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9100_galaxy_s_ii-3621.php) and [at Sony for the Vaio](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=SVF1521DCXW&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=manuals#/manualsTab).</sup>

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the Ubuntu part? I *guess* "put on NFC sign on my laptop" refers to some NFC tag, but I'm not sure. I've not heard NFC supported *directly* by some PC/laptop, so how should the actual transfer be accomplished? Are both devices connected to the same network (WiFi), so NFC should just trigger the transfer? Maybe you can [edit] your question and explain your intended workflow? E.g. "select a photo in the gallery app, hold my phone to the NFC tag, and the photo gets copied to the `/home/peter/Photos` folder"?

Comment: @Izzy Hi, Yes I mean when I turned on my NFC on my phone with android 4.2 gelibean in it and then I don't know what do I have to do that I can able transfer the photo to my pc. When I select share icon (a shape like "<:") I don't see any NFC share capability, And without doing any thing (just turning on NFC on phone) I putted it on NFC tag on my laptop and nothing transfer or I don't hear any sound. I also enabled NFC on my Ubuntu by `rfkill unblock all` and I see my NFC is ON in Ubuntu. But sir Izzy I don't know about same network. Does that need in NFC transfer.

Comment: ... [Here it is my laptop spec](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=SVF1521DCXW&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=manuals#/manualsTab) Please add my @KasiyA link before your comments because I don't receive any flag for your response on this question thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: @KasiyA NFC is normally used for the "handshake" only, while the file exchange itself is done with other means (either Bluetooth, or WiFi Direct). That's how it's done between two Android devices: hold them back-to-back, tap the "object" to-be-transferred, and the other device receives it. You'll probably need [nfctool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nfctool.1.html) or [libnfc](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc) on the Ubuntu-End; as I've not played with that, I cannot give any advice, sorry.

Comment: @Izzy I also did that(back to back) on Ubuntu and I did also on windows 8. I hear a sound on my Win8 and it opens a url on chrome browser but I get nothing to transfer. Thank you for suggest tools I will try with them.

Comment: @KasiyA If the question was posted by you, you should ask a mod to "merge users", so you can easily edit it yourself (did the edit for you meanwhile). // [nfctool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nfctool.1.html) should at least show whether Ubuntu *sees* your S2. Maybe the Ubuntu part is better asked at our sister site ("How to receive via/use NFC with Ubuntu?") – but the [NFC topic is not really wide-spread there either].(http://askubuntu.com/search?q=nfc).

Comment: @Izzy Yes it was for me but I deleted my user from here because I get no answer or even no comment(low reputation ;() until I came back here and Opened a bounty. I also asked on ASK U but as the same response there I deleted my question from there too. ;(

Answer (score -4):

You can try Airdroid as it available even for Ubuntu OS. It is one of the easiest way to transfer from PC to mobile or vice versa.

Go to Google Store and look for Airdroid and have it in your mobile.
On browser type - http://web.airdroid.com
Put in your user name and pass -> Boom you will have complete control of your mobile from your system.

If you like to know Airdroid's feature then you can check this out - [Airdroid Features](http://justclickin.com/airdroid-app-features/)

Comment: Full disclosure is required when promoting an app or post in which you are involved. Self promotion is fine as long as it is relevant *and* you disclose your involvement with the linked content.

Comment: In general I agree, with the stipulation that *it has to actually answer the question*. The question here wasn't "how can I transfer files between my S2 and my Vaio?", it's specifically about using NFC. If someone asks how to get a specific feature to work, then I think an answer that says "never mind that feature, try my app that accomplishes what you're trying to do in a different way" is just spam.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is only interested in accomplishing the ultimate goal, but that can't just be assumed. If he asked about NFC, it may be that he's specifically interested in figuring out this particular feature, no just asking how to transfer files in general. Personally, if I asked a question about getting NFC to work, I'd be annoyed if someone answered "Forget about NFC, here's another way to transfer files..." Especially if the person were promoting his own app, as an answer to a bountied question, no less!